# Subsonic:Selfjoin query need

Tags: subsonic

I want to construct the query which is going to be used in .net. Below you can see the sql query, any one can give me the equivalent subsonic query

> ```
> SELECT DISTINCT
>   a2.AccountID AS BID,
>   a2.AccountName AS Brand
> FROM
>   Account a
>   INNER JOIN Account a2 ON a.ParentID = a2.AccountID
> WHERE
>   a.AccountTypeID = 6
> ORDER BY
>   Brand
> ```

Please help me.

Answer (score 0):

SubSonic 2 or 3?

With SubSonic you always have a nice backdoor.

It's called InlineQuery in 2.x and CodingHorror in 3.x

e.g:

```
var result = DB.Query().ExecuteReader("SELECT DISTINCT
      a2.AccountID AS BID,
      a2.AccountName AS Brand
   FROM Account a
     INNER JOIN Account a2 ON a.ParentID = a2.AccountID
   WHERE a.AccountTypeID = ?accounttypeid
   ORDER BY Brand", 6);
```

If you want to stay with the fluent interface because of the syntax checking and the sql conversion. Here is another approach I could think of (SubSonic 2.2)

```
        DataTable result = DB.Select(
                "a1." + Account.Columns.AccountId + " as BID",
                "a2." + Account.Columns.AccountName + " as Brand")
            .From(Account.Schema.QualifiedName + " a1")
            .InnerJoin(Account.Schema.QualifiedName + " a2", 
                      "a2." + Account.Columns.account_id,
                "a1", "a1." + Account.Columns.parent_id)
            .Where("a1." + Account.Columns.AccountTypeId).IsEqualTo(6)
            .OrderAsc("a2." + Account.Columns.AccountName)
            .ExecuteDataSet().Tables[0];
```

But I never did this and I haven't verified it. But maybe it works.